# Interactuar con una página web Python3

Tags: python-3.x, web

Mi duda era más que nada si se puede crear un programa en `python` para interactuar dentro de una página web.

Por ejemplo, en Facebook, desde el programa le digo que abra la página `index` de la web en cuestión y que ingrese los datos de inicio de sesión, y que luego abra un chat x y mande un mensaje.

¿Este tipo de cosas se puede hacer en `python3`? no importa si hay que instalar módulos externos. ¿O sería más simple en otro lenguaje? Desde ya, gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si lo que preguntas es cómo, desde tu propio ordenador (y no desde el servidor como ha asumido la otra respuesta), poder conectarte a un servidor como si fueras un usuario utilizando el navegador, la respuesta general es que, sí, por supuesto que se puede. A fin de cuentas un navegador no es más que otro programa, el servidor a priori no sabe si está respondiendo a un usuario real o a un programa (por eso tantos sitios tienen *captchas*).

La respuesta más larga depende de qué pretendas hacer. Para "bajarse" simplemente una página, analizar el HTML y usarlo para bajarse contenido extra (por ejemplo, las imágenes, datos de una tabla, etc.) puedes usar la biblioteca [`requests`](https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/#), que te permite hacer peticiones GET (y otras), junto con alguna biblioteca de *scraping* como [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) para hacer búsquedas en el HTML obtenido.

Si necesitas interacciones más complejas, como loguearse primero y después "navegar" por el sitio dentro de la misma sesión, la cosa se complica. La biblioteca `requests` puede seguir siendo útil para esto, pues tiene el concepto de ["Session"](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#id1) que guarda todas las *cookies* que el servidor te envía, y se las reenvía de nuevo en cada petición subsiguiente, lo que hace que el servidor pueda identificar todas esas peticiones como parte de una misma sesión, correspondientes a un mismo usuario previamente logueado. El problema es que tienes que tener claro cómo funciona el formulario de registro, para poder hacer desde `requests` un POST que incluya todos los campos pertinentes. A menudo, además de tu nombre de usuario y contraseña, los formularios contienen campos ocultos que el servidor te ha enviado y que debes enviar tú también.

Finalmente, para interacciones más complejas con páginas dinámicas, en las que el navegador no se limita tan solo a enviar peticiones y recibir respuestas, sino que además ejecuta localmente JavaScript que modifica el aspecto de la página y que puede por sí mismo hacer peticiones adicionales sin la interacción del usuario, la cosa es realmente compleja. Especialmente porque Python no puede ejecutar JavaScript y por tanto no puede emular por completo lo que haría el navegador. Y me temo que este sería el caso para lo de interactuar con un chat.

Pero incluso este caso tiene solución. Mediante la biblioteca [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), Python puede arrancar un navegador real (por ejemplo Firefox o Chrome) y "teledirigirlo", haciendo sobre él las acciones que haría el usuario, como escribir en cajas de texto, pulsar botones, etc.

No obstante, aunque es posible, requiere conocer bien el funcionamiento de las varias tecnologías que usa el navegador, especialmente a la hora de seleccionar los elementos de la página con los que quieras interactuar. Debes conocer qué es el DOM, cómo seleccionar en él elementos, ya sea por clase o por id, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No se puede al menos que sea un espacio (hosting) propio es decir que usted haya comprado y que tenga disponible el uso de Python, por lo general el uso del lenguaje PHP es más común.  También hay páginas que ofrecen servicios gratuitos de hosting para luego vender más espacio u otros servicios (como heroku, que soporta Python y otros lenguajes como Node) .  Se puede comprar un dominio (nombre de página) y hacer que redireccione a estos hostings gratuitos.